# override record value in extjs

Tags: extjs4.1

I have the following code

```
    var record = form.getRecord();
    var values = form.getValues();
    record.set(values); 
   // record.data.DeliveryFrom = "test1";
    record.set('DeliveryFrom', 'test2');
    record.save();
```

I wish to override the property DeliveryFrom after i get the values from my form. However i when i view the results in firebug DeliveryFrom is null.  You will see above i tried 2 different ways to set this value.

I'm using extjs 4.1

Comment: take a look at this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762050/ext-js-4-convert-json-object-to-another-json-object-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This *should* work (assuming that form its `Ext.form.Basic)` if not (if its `Ext.form.Panel`), then use `form.getForm()`:

```
var record = form.getRecord();
form.updateRecord(record); //We use update record, its almost the same as you were using but in just one call
record.beginEdit(); //Put the record in edit mode
record.set( 'DeliveryFrom', 'test2');
record.endEdit(); //End editing the record and commit changes
record.save(); //Commit changes to backend
```