# Ext JS 4: Convert JSON object to another JSON object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs

What is the easiest way to convert JSON A to JSON B using JavaScript?

**JSON A:**

```
{
    "d":
    [
        {"__type":"Web.Controls.Shared.GeneralService+DropdownKeyValuePair","key":"0","value":"one"},
        {"__type":"Web.Controls.Shared.GeneralService+DropdownKeyValuePair","key":"1","value":"two"},
        {"__type":"Web.Controls.Shared.GeneralService+DropdownKeyValuePair","key":"2","value":"three"}
    ]
}
```

**JSON B:**

```
{
    data:
    [
        {"key":"1", "value":"one"},
        {"key":"2", "value":"two"},
        {"key":"3", "value":"three"}
    ]
}
```

===================

## 8/1/2012 update (answer when using Ext JS and you have an ASP.NET proxy:

I didn't provide this in my question about what I'm using for a JavaScript framework, but it turns out you can implicitly eliminate the "d" key by specifying the value "d" in the root property

```
var statusDropdownStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy: new Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy({
        url: '/track/Controls/Shared/GeneralService.asmx/GetDropdownOptions',
        actionMethods: {
            create: 'POST',
            destroy: 'DELETE',
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'POST'
        },
        extraParams: {
            user_login: authUser,
            table_name: '[status]'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            model: 'DropdownOption',
            root: 'd'
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    })
});
```

**Proxy:**

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    require: 'Ext.data',

    buildRequest: function (operation) {
        var params = Ext.applyIf(operation.params || {}, this.extraParams || {}),
                                request;
        params = Ext.applyIf(params, this.getParams(params, operation));
        if (operation.id && !params.id) {
            params.id = operation.id;
        }

        params = Ext.JSON.encode(params);

        request = Ext.create('Ext.data.Request', {
            params: params,
            action: operation.action,
            records: operation.records,
            operation: operation,
            url: operation.url
        });
        request.url = this.buildUrl(request);
        operation.request = request;
        return request;
    }
});
```

**Combo Box (dropdown) configuration:**

```
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        fieldLabel: 'Status',
                        emptyText: 'Select a status...',
                        store: statusDropdownStore,
                        valueField: 'key',
                        displayField: 'value',
                        mode: 'remote',  // or 'local'
                        renderTo: document.body
                    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do it:

```
var TheJsonA = JSON.parse(JsonA);
TheJsonA = TheJsonA.d;

var TheJsonB = {};
TheJsonB.data = [];
var TheObject = {};

if (TheJsonA.length > 0) { 

  for (var i = 0, LoopTimes = TheJsonA.length; i < LoopTimes; i++) {
      TheObject = {};
      TheObject.key = TheJsonA[i].key;
      TheObject.value = TheJsonA[i].value;
      TheJsonB.data.push(TheObject);
  }
}

TheJsonA = null; // if you need to discard the initial object
```

I also this JsonB shouldn't be an object that contains an array of objects; I think it should just be an array of objects like this:

```
[
     {"key":"1", "value":"one"},
     {"key":"2", "value":"two"},
     {"key":"3", "value":"three"}
]
```

Comment: you are precisely right about only having the array as the object!  See the bottom of my question in regards to how ExtJS allows you to remove the "d" property.  I guess the "__type" property stays there.. doesn't hurt anything since we explicitly state the "key" and "value" in the combo configuration.

Comment: "key" being the valueField value property and "value" being the displayField value

Comment: Yes, you can use ExtJS to extract the array from the wrapping object but that's heavy artillery! The second line of code does it by reassigning the elements inside .d to the wrapping object itself: TheNewObject = TheNewObject.d; Happy coding!!

Comment: Have you ever eaten at Frenchies on Clearwater Beach?  (near Tampa/St. Petersburg) Great Food!

Comment: No, but have you ever eaten in Paris, France?

Comment: Nope, but I once ate in Lourdes when I was 10.  I remember they served my milk with ice because I asked for it cold.

Comment: I guess that's kinda like using ExtJS to extract a property from an object. Good luck with your programming.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample

```
var old = {
    "d":
    [
        {"__type":"Web.Controls.Shared.GeneralService+DropdownKeyValuePair","key":"0","value":"one"},
        {"__type":"Web.Controls.Shared.GeneralService+DropdownKeyValuePair","key":"1","value":"two"},
        {"__type":"Web.Controls.Shared.GeneralService+DropdownKeyValuePair","key":"2","value":"three"}
    ]
};

old.data = old.d;
delete old.d;
for(var i=0,l=old.data.length;i<l;i++){
    delete old.data[i].__type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the solution outlined at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219633/832457 - using `delete` to remove the key.

Try looping through the array and using `delete`, then rename the array (by creating a new attribute and the deleting the old one

Answer (score 1):

try this :)
http://jsfiddle.net/daewon/LnpXb/

```
var jsonA = {
    d: [
        {"__type":"Web.Controls.Shared.GeneralService+DropdownKeyValuePair","key":"0","value":"one"},
        {"__type":"Web.Controls.Shared.GeneralService+DropdownKeyValuePair","key":"1","value":"two"},
        {"__type":"Web.Controls.Shared.GeneralService+DropdownKeyValuePair","key":"2","value":"three"}
   ]
};

var jsonB = {
    data: []
};

var d = jsonA.d;
for (var i=0; i<​d.length​; i++){
    var obj = {
        key : d[i].key,
        value : d[i].value
    };

    jsonB.data.push(obj);    
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonB));
=> {"data":[{"key":"0","value":"one"},{"key":"1","value":"two"},{"key":"2","value":"three"}]}
```

​